# HTMLElement.click() not working in IE10 for custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, quote

I created a custom button on the **Quote** object that executes JavaScript, and everything works fine except for a critical call to [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click). The kickers to this problem are:

- The button works fine in Firefox and Chrome, just *not* in **IE10**
- The same code works when I run it from IE10's developer tools Console

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? And any workarounds?

I can reproduce the problem consistently via the following steps:

1. Create and *activate* at least two new quote templates, e.g., "United States Standard Template" and "United Kingdom Standard Template"
2. Create a custom button on the Quote object labeled "Create My PDF", which executes the following JavaScript: `document.getElementById("createpdf").click();`
3. Add the custom button to an applicable Quote page layout, making sure the standard Create PDF is also present
4. Open **IE10**, and on a Quote detail page, click the **Create My PDF** button. Nothing happens. But if you press F12 and run the exact same JavaScript in the Console, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper into the standard Create PDF button, I discovered a hidden anchor element that contained the actual JavaScript call for selecting a template. I modified my code to click this anchor tag instead, using jQuery.

```
$(".chooseTemplates")[0].click();
```